# what happens when router memory filled?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

what happens when router memory filling ?
i know that router when memory filled after isn't net available and internet is turn off before router do not make router restart .
and else interested me. what moment fill memory ?

asus memory .
[image: http://www.asus.com/websites/global/products/PZkFHlMrGWzVROxT/transparent.jpg]

Comment: It's really hard to understand this question. Any chance you could reword it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few things that can go wrong if your router runs out of memory.  This is assuming a SOHO router running Linux or other embedded operating system.  Business/carrier grade routers may act differently.

- Tracking TCP connections requires a bit of memory from the system doing so.  If a router's memory is completely full, it may not respond to incoming TCP connections, making them drop.  Existing ones should continue to work.
- Tracking NAT sessions also requires a bit of memory per incoming request.  If memory is completely full, your system may fail to forward new connections to the Internet or be unable to forward incoming connections.  This would affect any incoming IP protocol, not just TCP.
- The embedded web server on your router providing the web interface will either create a new process to satifsy attempts to access it, or allocate more memory to handle the request.  If RAM is full, this can't happen, and the router's web interface may not work at all, or certain assets won't load, or may have trouble loading.
- A similar situation exists for any telnet or SSH server running on the router.  Your router may be unable to spawn a login process or shell if there is not enough RAM.
- A similar situation exists for any service running on your router, such as `dnsmasq` or any DHCP server.  It may be unable to allocate memory or spawn processes to handle new requests and may stop responding.  Some services may terminate abnormally if that happens, some may just stop responding.

256MB is a lot of memory for a router so you should not run into any issues unless you are doing something really weird.

Comment: i offten turn off internet probably because that ram is filled .

Comment: If you can access the web interface or telnet/SSH into it then RAM being full is not the issue.

Comment: i know ram is full filled and i interested that don't will full fill memory what will do i such ?

i don;'t want that my router internet will turn off .
what will do i that memory don't will fill ?

Comment: @TokaZviadauri The RAM being filled is perfectly normal and has nothing to do with the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you can tell me when router memory is filled this cause was ? 

http://atechjourney.com/wp-content/uploads/dns-server-not-responding.jpg

so when interneti turn off troubleshoot got this problem and maybe problem be this memory fill ?

and else when net turn off i can't open anything website just i can open router configuration page or other ip .

Comment: @TokaZviadauri You're making your problem impossible to troubleshoot by, for absolutely no reason, obsessing about router memory being filled.

Comment: then please tell me what is cause . 

other cause i isn't know

Comment: if i will buy better router will be again problem ?

Comment: @TokaZviadauri I don't know either. You can try asking a question about your problem, providing as much information as you can about your configuration, hardware, and symptoms. This is a question and answer site, after all.

Comment: my net provider don't know , i already call and told me make router reset but again i have problem . 

so you told me that this problem isn't fault router memory ?

Comment: @TokaZviadauri There are lots of people who would be happy to help you diagnose your problem, but you don't seem to want to ask.

Comment: who ask my question , you can ask and after tell me answer ?

Comment: i that show you my router system log ?

you learn what is problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens. Devices run perfectly normally even with their memory completely filled. Commodity routers are designed as a complete system and the amount of memory provided by the hardware is chosen such that the router will not encounter problems while operating.

Comment: Surely that can't be right. Perhaps "whilst operating under normal loads", i.e when there's memory left. What happens when its mac table or routing tables are full and it needs to add another entry? All traffic being processed has some memory overhead; what happens when there's no capacity to deal with these? Connections will start timing out, right?

Comment: probably happens because my internet turn off and cause is router internet isn't available before don't make router restart

Comment: @RJFalconer I understood the OP to be asking about RAM, not MAC tables or routing tables. These tables have limits that such that they can all hit their limits at the same time without issues.

Comment: @TokaZviadauri That has nothing to do with RAM. SoHo routers have enough RAM that you can hit all their limits at the same time without RAM being a problem.

Comment: where should buy soho ? 

fine is ?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of hardware like [Cisco 1800 Series](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/1800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/index.html), when the router RAM is filled up it will experience traffic degradation and locks in the processing. In the case of home/office ones, they are made to work fine in small networks, so nothing happens.

Comment: what will do i ? that ram don;t will fill

Comment: SOHO routers haves several problemas with temperature ,locks could be for that cause too.

Comment: how to will use low memory that don;t will turn off ?